# How can I check how many elements are inside one field?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a piece of code in my HTML:

```html
<div class="all-homes">
  <div class="home">RED</div>
  <div class="home">WHITE</div>
  <div class="home">GREEEN</div>
  <div class="home">BLUE</div>
</div>
```

I need to remove `home` from the list only if in the class of `all-homes` there are more than 1 `home`. Otherwise there should be a warning message saying that you can't remove `home` because there is just 1 `home` in the list. Would that be possible?

I was try:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {

if  (document.getElementsByClassName("all-homes") "how to gete the right informatuion here" ) {
 event.run();
}else {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submit
    swal({
  title: "Remove Home",
  text: " text",
  icon: "warning",

});

  }
}
</script>
```

My remove Button:

```
<p>{{home_at_homes_pk}}</p> //this is the home list

    <form method='post' action="{% url 'home_at_homes_delete' home_at_homes_pk=home_at_homes_slug%}">
             {% csrf_token %}
              <button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()"  id="remove-location"       class="txt-button alert icon-link" style="margin-top: 0rem;">
           <span class="icon">
           <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
           </span>
           Remove Home
           </button>
        </form>
```

*update from comment*:
 **I want to remove the whole elements until one is left**

Thank you very much

Comment: Sure, it's possible but i don't get your requirements. Do you want to remove the css-class 'home' from the div's? Or do you want to remove the whole elements until one is left?

Comment: Your condition isn't clear

Comment: Can you share the full html?

Comment: Looks like it's remove the "parent" (with `class='all-homes'`), really needs a better sample / examples

Comment: Kris that's right, I want to remove the whole elements until one is left

Comment: So which one should be left? Please show your JS code so we can help you debug it. SO is here to debug code, not to write it for you

Comment: could you show us what you've tried ?

Comment: I need to be able to remove all the homes until there is only one, there should be one in any case

Comment: @3ru10mon Which one? First one? Last one? middle one?

Comment: can be random, all the home have also a remove home button

Comment: So: on the click on the "remove" button, check that it's not the only sibling.  `if ($(this).closest(".home").siblings(".home").length == 0) { /* block remove */ } else { /* allow remove */ }` or `if($(this).closest(".all-home").find(".home").length > 1) { /* allow remove */ }` - if you include where your "remove" button is in your sample, this could be more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   function myFunction() {

     var all = document.getElementsByClassName("all-homes")[0];

     while (all.children.length > 1) {
        console.log(all.children.length)
        all.children[0].remove();
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully answer your question

```js
const red = document.getElementById('red');

jQuery('#remove').on('click', () => {
    const elements = $('#red').children('.home');
    if(elements.length > 1) {
        for( let i=0; i< elements.length - 1; ++i){
            $(elements[i]).remove();
        }
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="red">
    <div class="home">WHITE</div>
    <div class="home">GREEN</div>
    <div class="home">BLUE</div>
</div>
<button id="remove">Remove home</button>
```

Comment: Instead of `.find` I suggest `.children`. A more efficient and arguably more as expected :)

Comment: I would agree with you. if he mean the direct children better to use children. Updated my answer. Thanks

Comment: Will it be possible to choose which one to remove instead of removing all of them?

Comment: What is the condition that need to fulfill to remove the element?